# Unit Testing Bluetooth SDK on iOS Devices

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth, xctest, kif

I'm working on an SDK which does Bluetooth operations with the peripheral device. 
I wrote some Unit tests for my SDK using XCTest framework. Since my API's use Bluetooth I can't test on an simulator also XCTest doesn't run on the tests on the device.

Is there a way to test libraries on an actual device ? or Do I need to test using an sample app which uses all my API's ?

I know that KIF can be used to automate tests on physical device, Can I use KIF to test just the SDK  ?

Any useful response is much appreciated.

Comment: You can run unit tests on a device, you just have to convert them into "application" tests (so that they use an app bundle, it might even be a "dummy" empty app).